# Column and row vectors (spinors) in Landau-Lifshitz vol.IV Theoretical Physics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I am getting confused by the notation the authors of this book since they define:
$$
\bar{\psi}\equiv \psi^\ast \gamma^0
$$
where (I suppose) $^\ast$ means complex conjugate and $\gamma^0$ is one of the Dirac matrices.

To me this looks like a complete nonsense since $\psi$ and $\psi^\ast$ are a column vectors and $\gamma^0$ is a square matrix and I have never seen such a thing as ''column per row'' product.

At first I thought it could siply mean that the author used the notation $^\ast$ instead of $^\dagger$ meaning thus complex conjugate and transposition:
$$
\bar{\psi}\equiv \psi^\ast \gamma^0=\psi^\dagger \gamma^0.
$$

But then other derivations do not make sense, such as the following:
$$
{\psi}^C = U_C\bar{\psi}
$$
$$
\bar{\psi}^C\equiv 
\left[U_C\bar{\psi}\right]^\ast \gamma^0 = 
\left[U_C(\psi^\ast \gamma^0)\right]^\ast\gamma^0= 
\left[U_C^\ast(\psi \gamma^{0\ast})\right]\gamma^0
$$
where apparently they really mean just conjugate otherwise they sould have swapped all the stuff in the square bracket:
$$
\left[U_C(\psi^\ast \gamma^0)\right]^\dagger\gamma^0= 
\left[(\gamma^{0\dagger}\psi )U_C^\dagger\right]\gamma^0.
$$

Pleas enlighten me!

EDIT: I also found out the authors use the following:
$$
\bar{\psi}\left[\gamma (p+eA) + m\right] = 0\\
\left[\tilde{\gamma} (p+eA) + m\right]\bar{\psi}=0
$$
where $\tilde{}$ means transpose.
So I guess they just use it as a row or column vector depending on what they need...

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Myridium I actually completely forgot about it. I guess I concluded that they were just a bit sloppy and left the transpose sign mostly implicit depending on the context...